# How to show last reached Activity When open Application?

Tags: android-activity

User plays game.Then user click backkey to home.Then user replays game.I want to
show user  last used screen.

Comment: Please show me example code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic problem about saving data in android in fact.

Referring to [android saving data training](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html), you can use the way you like to saving data. For you, the data is about which activity, what is on this activity. In your condition, I recommend you to use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) API.

You can use the method [onPause()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause()) do something about saving data such as your activity name, for example, com.x.x.XXActivity, then in your MainActivity(Which means that the activity will be launched first) start this activity by [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

This all.